# Remove floating useless 0 in C

Tags: c, floating-point

How can I remove the zeros that will not affect the number value

```
 float X1 = (-b + sqrt(pow(b,2) - (4*a*c)))/(2*a);
```

sometimes if the X1 was a number without a decimal it will be `X1=4.0000`
how can I avoid that

{edited}

Comment: Please show the code so we can give you suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and rephrase your question

Comment: you need truncation in display or in value?

Comment: try `printf("%g\n",4.000);` or `snprintf` then delete `.` and `0`

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"useless zero"*

Comment: Is this in output (e.g: `printf()`)? Or in source (e.g: `float x = 4.000`)? More information required...

Comment: From a certain perspective `42.` isn't the same as `42.0` isn't the same as `42.00` isn't the same as ...

Comment: Always prefer `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: Are the zeroes here useless? 4.0000000000000001?

Comment: *"how can I avoid that"* - you can't, it's part of the data type (and therefore required) - you can however choose not to show it in output (or cast to an integer type and lose the additional information)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### option #1

Use `%g` of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

> Unless alternative representation is requested the trailing zeros are
>   removed, also the decimal point character is removed if no fractional
>   part is left.

code sample:

```
double x = 4.0;
printf("DEBUG:%f\n", x);
printf("X1=%g\n", x);
```

OUTPUT:

```
DEBUG:4.000000
X1=4
```

### option #2

Output it to a string and process it.

code sample:

```
double x = 4.0;
char buff[48];
int len;
len = snprintf(buff, sizeof buff, "%.4f", x);
printf("DEBUG:%s\n", buff);
char *p = buff + len -1;
while(*p == '0'){
    *p-- = 0;
}
if(*p == '.')
    *p = 0;
printf("X1=%s\n", buff);
```

OUTPUT:

```
DEBUG:4.0000
X1=4
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Tarek accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.